# How to check nil string in if condition swift

Tags: ios, swift

So when I press the button I check if both the UITextField and the UITextView have some value inside them, but if they are nil then perform this.

So I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var defTextView = UITextView

@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if let definitionName = defTextView.text {

        print(definitionName)

    } else {

        print("nil")

    }
}
```

Instead of receiving the word "nil" I got empty Strings bring printed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defTextView.text is empty String "" instead of nil.

Try where clause to check if it is empty:

```
@IBOutlet weak var defTextView = UITextView

@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if let definitionName = defTextView.text where !definitionName.isEmpty {

        print(definitionName)

    } else {

        print("nil")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, however, remember that an empty string is not `nil`. A `UITextView`'s text is unlikely to be nil, so I would use an if statement to check if it is an empty string, as well as than if let unwrapping.

For example, use this instead:

```
if let defenitionName = defTextView.text where defTextView.text != nil {
  print(definitionName)
} else {
  print("none") //Not necessarily nil.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try following code**

```
if defTextView.text != nil || !(defTextView.text == "")  {

    print(definitionName)

} else {

    print("nil")

}
```

Comment: I tried it with just if !(defTextView.text == "") {} and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually meaningless because the text of a text view is never `nil`.

According the documentation the property `text` of `UITextView` is an implicit unwrapped optional - unlike `UILabel` whose `text` can be `nil`.

So it's guaranteed to be not `nil` when it's used and you need only to check for an empty string, optional binding or `!= nil` is not needed.

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {

   let definitionName = defTextView.text
   if definitionName.isEmpty {
      print("definitionName is empty")
   } else {
      print("definitionName is not empty")
   }
}
```